# Fullcalendar axisFormat add 2 minutes

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm trying to create a events calendar using Fullcalendar JS And I'm stuck with axisFormat, its always add 2 minutes. How can i solve this problem?
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuNv9.png)

**Calendar JS from Index**

```
var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
              header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            minTime: '09:00',
            maxTime: '23:00',
            axisFormat: 'HH:MM',
            overlap: false,
            editable: false,
            selectable: true,
            slotEventOverlap: false,
            selectOverlap: false,
            eventOverlap: false,
            events: {
                url: "<?= URL::to('/data/schedule/futsal') ?>",
                beforeSend: function(intervalStart, intervalEnd){
                    console.log(moment(intervalStart).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS')+'#'+moment(intervalEnd).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS'));
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert("error!!!");   
                },
                success: function(index, data){
                    console.log(data);
                }
            }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have given wrong axisformat.

Try this

```
axisFormat: 'HH:mm',
```

You need to give [moment format](http://momentjs.com/docs/)

This will work for sure.

Comment: @Rahmat Please mark right sign so that other can get help from your question. Thanks :)